# Using HAML instead of ERB causes tests to fail

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, haml, ruby-on-rails-5, erb

This seems very basic, but I'm using Rails 5 and I swapped all of my views to HAML instead of ERB. Now one of my tests is failing saying the following:

```
ActionController::UnknownFormat: ProductsController#index is missing  a template for this request format and variant.

request.formats: ["text/html"]
request.variant: []
    test/controllers/products_controller_test.rb:9:in `block in <class:ProductsControllerTest>'
```

Is there anywhere to change the default, or is there another issue I have to address? My routes are fine, and I can access the index page no problem.

Comment: is title relevant?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need `haml` installed, add `gem 'haml'` to the Gemfile, next `bundle install` in your console.

Comment: Now I read that is the only test failing, can you show us the test?

Comment: I restarted my webserver. In my case sudo service nginx restart. And it picked up newly installed gem

Answer (score 1):

Seems that you are missing the view file `index.html.haml` in `app/views/products`

Comment: No, I have that file in the correct directory. The test passes when I change it back to index.html.erb. So it's the extension I'm using... Not sure why...

Comment: If that is the only view you have with haml extension then follow MaicolBen answer

Answer (score 0):

It means a missing template for the `#index` method in controller.
Rails has a convention, it will search for this file in `/views/` directory, the associated html.erb or haml file, following the name convention.

Answer (score 0):

I saw the same issue and the solution for us was caused by adding the haml gem into `development` group in the `Gemfile`, make sure the haml related gems are in no group